# Variable declared and assigned at global scope is undefined when called by a nested return function

Tags: javascript, arguments, parameter-passing, return-value, nested-function

When a function is created inside a function, the following code is returning a string with the `name` variable coming back as `undefined`.  Since this is functionally scoped inside the global scope, I would have expected the `name` variable from the global scope to be found and used.  Is the issue that parameter naming is not relevant for returned functions since these are only scoped inside the function?

My JavaScript code:

```
const name = "Ben"
function testReturn() {
  return function (name) {
    console.log(`Hello, ${name}`)
  }
}
```

And I called the function below:

```
> testReturn()()
Hello, undefined
undefined
```

Comment: The parameter `name` in `function (name)` shadows the outer variable. Either remove the parameter or pass it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global constant `name` is [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) by the local parameter `name`.

Give one of them a different name or, if you aren't going to use it, remove the parameter entirely.

```
const name = "Ben"
function testReturn() {
  return function () {
    console.log(`Hello, ${name}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you, felt like I was missing something simple.